# Do US ATMs need magnetic stripes?

Tags: debit-card, atm

German banks (credit unions) are starting to issue ATM cards that have only a chip, no magnetic stripes ([German language news article](http://www.heise.de/security/meldung/Sparkassen-tragen-den-Magnetstreifen-zu-Grabe-1031718.html)).

Can such a card currently (May 2014) be used in US ATM machines and points of sale, considering that chip and pin is still uncommon in the USA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

US ATMs and POS require magnetic strip, chip-and-pin only cards will not work almost anywhere in the US. This is starting to change, especially after the [Target fiasco](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tag/target-hack/), but we're not there yet.

Comment: Has the situation changed significantly in the past 3 years?

Comment: @gerrit - yes, they are now typically chip machines. - 7 yrs later!

Comment: @Fattie Unless littleadv changes their answer, perhaps you can add that as a separate answer?  I now have a German chip-only card and am going to the USA this year.

Comment: howdy @gerrit !  I'll let someone with specific numbers, maybe industry, details answer!  The general impression, certainly if you're going to major cities, is you'll have no major problem these days - they have finally slightly caught-up!